# SSIS DB write SQL query to pull report 1) Number of times executed 2) Success/Fail/Running 3) date of execution

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I need a SQL Query to run against SSISDB which should result in below format.

1. Package Name/Project Name
2. Number times Packages executed for Current date
3. Status=Success/Failure/Running
4. Execution Date

Please help.

Comment: It doesn't seem like you made any effort here. This is just a google away

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/system-views/catalog-executions-ssisdb-database), something along the lines of...

**Hacky version:**

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(package_name, '/', project_name) AS [Package Name/Project Name]
  , COUNT(execution_id) AS [Number times Packages executed for Current date]
  , FIRST_VALUE(status) OVER (PARTITION BY CONCAT(package_name, '/', project_name) ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS [Status]
  , CAST(start_time AS date) AS [Execution Date]
FROM catalog.executions
WHERE CAST(start_time AS date) = CAST(GETDATE() AS date)
GROUP BY CONCAT(package_name, '/', project_name), CAST(start_time AS date);
```

**Non-hacky version:**

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(e.package_name, '/', e.project_name) AS [Package Name/Project Name]
  , COUNT(e.execution_id) AS [Number times Packages executed for Current date]
  , st.[Status]
  , CAST(e.start_time AS date) AS [Execution Date]
FROM catalog.executions e
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT TOP(1) FIRST_VALUE(s_e.status) OVER (ORDER BY s_e.start_time DESC) AS [Status]
        FROM catalog.executions s_e
        WHERE CONCAT(e.package_name, '/', e.project_name) = CONCAT(s_e.package_name, '/', s_e.project_name)
            AND CAST(e.start_time AS date) = CAST(s_e.start_time AS date)
    ) st
WHERE CAST(e.start_time AS date) = CAST(GETDATE() AS date)
GROUP BY CONCAT(e.package_name, '/', e.project_name), CAST(e.start_time AS date);
```

Note that the status attribute is a number (described in the documentation). I also used `FIRST_VALUE()` function (available from SQL Server) just for the sake of it being practical but it can be avoided. Also, you might want to wrap this query in a CTE and then use a `CASE` statement based on `Status` to return the actual meaning of the number.

Comment: Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 4

Column 'catalog.executions.start_time' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. (Error message i got. Could you please help in correcting this.)

Comment: I apologize, I overlooked that. I did a small edit for the `OVER` clause, used a hacky way to determine the order in the window function.
**EDIT:** I'm also adding another piece of code that should be more stable then the hacky version

Comment: One last question. Foremost thanks for help. I see almost all time execution id as unique identifier. How we can consider it as occurance for that day. Thanks for your help

Comment: Well, `execution_id` is a `bigint`, not a `uniqueidentifier`... Not sure what exactly do you mean? As far as your question about the occurence of this day, I pretty much gave you a query that uses `WHERE` to filter out all the occurences that weren't in the current day. Therefore, as a result, you should be getting only this day. If you want to see results for all days, just remove the `WHERE` statement.